# Unity touch controls works at least 5-6 times in a second

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, touch

I'm trying to implement touch controls on my current Unity project.
I'm currently trying to execute this line of code, but I have seen that fps has dropped significantly and it executes lines about touch controls more than I expected.

```
for(int i=0;i<Input.touchCount;i++)
{
   Debug.log("Touched");
}
```

I'm curios about that, is there more effective way to get touch inputs from user both for IOS and Android, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you're using this in your Update function.
You need to do it that way :

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            Debug.Log("Touched");
        }
    }
}
```

That way it will only be called one time for a touch, at its begining.

The way you're doing it is "while the screen is touched, print 'Touched' in log".

If you want to do it for many fingers you can do

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        int countTouches = Input.touchCount;
        for (int i = 0; i < countTouches; i++)
        {
            if (Input.GetTouch(i).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
            {
                Debug.Log("Touched");
            }
        }
    }
}
```